Recuperación de contraseña, con partición de Windows aislado
Tengo una laptop Dell Latitude 3340. Accidentalmente he creado una partición aislada de windows, en el disco duro. Una vez quiero iniciar sesión en mi laptop me dice que no es la contraseña, que debo acceder a internet para comprobar, tengo conexión a internet, aún teniendo conexión a internet. También he modificado la contraseña de microsoft en línea, pensando que solucionaría el problema.
He intentado cambiar la contraseña con cmd, pero este no me abre porque me pide la contraseña de administrador, he probado diferentes opciones pero sigue igual.
Estoy actualmente intentando acceder a la información del disco duro, mediante un cable SATA desde otra laptop. El único problema que he enfrentado, es no saber dónde se encuentra la carpeta donde se almacena las cuentas, contraseñas o certificaciones para el inicio de sesión.

Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Yo para recuperaciones de contraseña en Windows use en unas cuantas ocasiones hiren's boot que es una imagen de disco que puedes montar en un pendrive también y lo ejecutas antes del sistema como si fueras a instalar un sistema operativo, desde ahí puedes quitar o modificar la contraseña y ponerla luego, yo lo he usado normalmente para quitar la contraseña, para luego ponerla desde el propio windows:
Esto lo he sacado de Hiren's BootCD PE que tiene entorno gráfico
https://www.labsmac.es/resetear-contrasena-de-windows-10-con-hirens-bootcd-pe/
Abrimos la carpeta Utilities > Security > Passwords y abrimos la aplicación NT Password Edit 

Se va abrir la aplicación NTPWEdit, clicamos en (1) Open para abrir la base de datos de SAM, en el apartado de (2) User list, elegimos el usuario al que reestablecer la contraseña y finalmente clicamos en (3) Change password.

Ahora nos saldrá la ventana para establecer la nueva contraseña de usuario y clicamos en OK

Para acabar clicamos en Save changes y en Exit para salir.

Después de estos pasos deberias poder entrar con la contraseña que has cambiado.
Espero que te sirva, un saludo ^^
